# Get a control's value that is in usercontrol using javascript

Tags: asp.net

I have a user control that i have registered to an aspx page. Now from the aspx page, i am trying to access one of the registered usercontrol's hiddenfield value in my aspx page using javacript using the below code:

tst = document.getElementById('control1$hdnField').value;

I looked into the page's trace, and i could see 'control1$hdnField'. Then why i am not getting its value in my aspx page. I have also ensured that the hidden field exits on the user control and has a default value set.

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you have is the `name` of the field, what you need is the `ID` of the field, which would have a `_` instead of `$` as a delimiter, like this:

```
var tst = document.getElementById('control1_hdnField').value;
```

Since your hidden `<input>`, I'm pretty sure looks like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="control1$hdnField" id="control1_hdnField" value="val" />
```

Comment: Tried this as well. But i am still getting 'Object Required' error.

Comment: No. I am using -- 
<asp:HiddenField ID="hdnField" runat="server" Value="Some Value" />

Comment: @flopdix - that's what it looks like in your markup...but when it gets rendered to the client the IDs get mangled a bit, prepending the naming container's it's in...unless you're using .Net 4, can you post what your **rendered** input looks like?

Comment: Ok. When i did View Source to my aspx page, i dont see hdnField in the markup. Is that expected? Because in the page trace, i am able to see Control1$hdnField.

Comment: No this script is in the aspx page. I am appending Control1/2/3 in the next iteration, so i wont have duplicate ids. I am still stuck, not getting, any ideas?

Comment: Will there be any other setting at the page or usercontrol level, that could be the cause?

Comment: @flopdix - If you give the user control a public property, say `public string HiddenFieldID { get { return hdnField.ClientID; } }` then in the page you can use `var tst = document.getElementById('<%=userControl.HiddenFieldID%>').value;` I'm not sure this is the best approach though...what are you trying to do, and are you using any javascript frameworks?  If you're doing a lot of scripting, a framework and dealing with classes bypasses a lot of these issues.